# After calling setTextColor, text does not appear in TextView

Tags: android

I have a custom cursor adapter and I am trying to set the color of a text box of one of the row views:

```
 txtChange.setTextColor(0xE01B4C);
 txtChange.setText("Hey I'm some Text!");
```

If I remove the `setTextColor` call the text appears as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A color value specifies an RGB value with an alpha channel, which can be used in various places such as specifying a solid color for a Drawable or the color to use for text. It always begins with a # character and then is followed by the alpha-red-green-blue information in one of the following formats: #RGB, #ARGB, #RRGGBB or #AARRGGBB.

So do one thing define your color inside the color.xml file as:

```
<color name="demo_color">#E01B4C</color>
```

And then access it as below:

```
 txtChange.setTextColor(R.color.demo_color);
```

### Or

you can also define in the XML layout file itself:

```
android:textColor="#E01B4C"
```

Comment: Thanks. Got me headed in the right direction. The way I actually got it to work was: txtChange.setTextColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.demo_color))

Comment: @Adam glad about your reply !! and the way you mentioned that is also valid.

Comment: @Adam: The getResources part is a method so it should be getResources(). See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177273/textview-settextcolor-not-working