# TextView setTextColor() not working

Tags: android, colors, textview

I programmatically create a list (no a ListView, just adding them to the parent) of such elements:

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/filiale_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lagerstand_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp" android:textColor="@color/red"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, I have defined some colors in values/colors.xml. As you see, the TextView with id "lagerstand_text" has set it's color to red by default. That works.

When creating the elements in Java, I do

```
lagerstandText.setText("bla");
```

and for some elements also I do

```
lagerstandText.setTextColor(R.color.red);
```

and other colors. While the elements on which I don't call setTextColor() are red, all others are grey, no matter which color I chose (even if it's the same red again).

Why is that?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

The documentation is not very verbose about this, but you cannot use just the R.color integer when calling `setTextColor`.  You need to call `getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR)` to set a color properly.

Use the following to set color of your text programmatically:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR));
```

Starting with the support library 23 you have to use the following code, because getColor is deprecated:

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.YOURCOLOR));
```

Comment: Ok, that works. The API documentation could be a bit more verbose in this case...

Comment: also u can use Color. ( here red green black blue yellow and other) setTextColor(Color.RED)

Comment: Thanks for the info... but this getResources() makes me pass a chain of contexts. There should be some better way to accessing global resources.

Comment: @Umair Use a static variable on your Application class.

Comment: @Kontinuity, I read that keeping the context in static variable is big source of memory leakage.

Comment: @Umair http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android

Comment: Its working for me if i use R.color.green. But not working if i use android.R.color.white. Any idea why?

Comment: getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR) has been deprecated in v23.  See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23) for the new way

Answer (score 35):

So, there are many ways to achieve this task.

**1.**

```
int color = Integer.parseInt("bdbdbd", 16)+0xFF000000;
textview.setTextColor(color);
```

**2.**

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
```

**3.**

```
textView.setTextColor(0xffbdbdbd);
```

**4.**

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
```

**5.**

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.argb(a_int, r_int, g_int, b_int));
```

Comment: Is there any way to find out if a particular color value is going to make the text disappear?

Comment: I'm adjusting the brightness of the color before using setTextColor(color). In some unknown cases the TextView simply disappears on the device (independent of the background). I want to write a test function to check if "color" is a valid color value before using it in setTextColor(color).

Comment: @ChristopherMasser not trying anything what u said ??

Answer (score 4):

1.standard color u prefer please go with below .

```
textview.setTextColor(Color.select_color)
```

2.here want to use custwom color add it in color.xml file

```
textview.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textbody));
```

or

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

or

```
subText.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,192,0));
```

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, you can use the follow:

```
String color = getString(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(R.color.my_color)));
my_textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
```

This way you can make use of your Color Resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: What makes your answer different from the one posted by other members?

Answer (score 0):

The integer id for a particular color(defined in xml layout) defined in `R` class cannot be passed as a parameter to `setTextColor()` method of `View` class.
You must obtain the parameter of the `setTextColor()` by the following line of code :

```
int para=getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color,null);
view.setTextColor(para,null);
```

The method `getColor(int id)` has been depreciated...instead use `getColor(int id,Resources.Theme theme)` as in the line of code above.

```
The `second parameter( theme )` can be null
```