# programmatically setTextColor in TextView in library 22 in Android

Tags: android, colors, textview

Recently I changed a little bit of my app and for a reason I don't understand the "setTextColor" method seems that it no longer works.

In my XML, I have a listview and I programmatically add TextViews in this listView.

XML:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_game_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="7dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
textView = new TextView(getContext());
    textView.setText("some text");
    textView.setTextSize(20f);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setTextAppearance(getContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
    addView(textView);
```

But this text is white whatever I do.
Why?

Comment: this is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177273/textview-settextcolor-not-working

Comment: Try removing the "setTextAppearance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did try your code and I guess the troubling factor was `setTextAppearance`. In fact calling `setTextColor()` after this call fixed the issue. The below code is working perfectly for me:

```
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("some text");
        textView.setTextSize(20f);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        // textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        // setContentView(textView);
```

I don't know the true reason for this issue.

Comment: Thank you, it solves my problem.
Instead of other solutions because i'm still in library 22.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to set color of your text programmatically:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR));
```

Starting with the support library 23 you have to use the following code, because getColor is deprecated:

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.YOURCOLOR));
```

See this: [TextView setTextColor() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177273/textview-settextcolor-not-working?answertab=active#tab-top])

Comment: Thanks, but i forgot to say that i'm still in library 22. The answer that fix my problem is the one next to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 ResourceCompact.getColor(getResources(), R.color.your_id, null);
```

The `getResources().getColor()` method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

instead of:

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```